# How to get image to display instead of raw data php/html?

Tags: php, html, image, dropbox-api

I've written code that copies uploaded images to dropbox and managed to retrieve the thumbnail raw data succesfuly but it only displays the raw data and not image. So I tried saving a thumbnail in php when the user uploads the image and it does the same thing. I must be missing out a step or something on both occasions. Also the thumbnails are suppose to save on web server but it doesn't.

**HTML**

```
<form name="upload" id="upload" action="postuploads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>File to upload : <input type ="file" name = "fuploads"></p><br />
    <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Upload Image">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<body>

<?php
    # Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
    require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
    use \Dropbox as dbx;

    /* grant access */
    $accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
    $accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

    /* Copy file to dropbox */
    $f2 = fopen($_FILES["fuploads"]["tmp_name"], "rb"); 
    $target_file = basename($_FILES["fuploads"]["name"]);   
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

    $result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/AEE1292838/101/" . $target_file, dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f2);

    $filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
    $source = $_FILES['fuploads']['tmp_name'];

    $target = $filename;

    if($imageFileType=="jpg"){
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    }
    if($filetype=="png"){
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($source);  
    }
    if($filetype=="gif"){
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    }

    $origX = imagesx($im);
    $origY = imagesy($im);
    $newX = 250;
    $newY = 250;

    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($newX,$newY);

    imagecopyresized($nm,$im,0,0,0,0, $newX,$newY,$origX,$origY);

    imagejpeg($nm,$target);
    fclose($f2);    
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $target ; ?>" title="thumbs" />    
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post a printscreen of what is happening? And echo the `$filename` outside the image source so we can see what value is being applied.

Comment: Ok working now! I missed by s ....$filename = $_FILES['fupload????']['name']; adding the s in works! thanks..